# How to skip an 'if' statement if a value doesn't change Hangman Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logic

I am doing a coding exercise using jQuery/Javascript to make a hangman game. Most functionality of my game works: getting new word, updating guesses, etc. however the problem lies within the **function reviewLives()** concerning the if statements and the draw functions called. Here is the code:

```js
//Draw functions
function drawHead() {
  $('.draw-area').append($('<div>').addClass("body-part head"));
}
function drawTorso() {
  $('.draw-area').append(
   $('<div>').addClass("body-part armbox").append(
     $('<div>').addClass("body-part torso")));
  $('.draw-area').append(
   $('<div>').addClass("body-part legbox").append(
     $('<div>').addClass("body-part pelvis")));
}
function drawLeftArm(){
  $('.armbox').prepend($('<div>').addClass('body-part leftarm'));
}
function drawRightArm(){
  $('.armbox').prepend($('<div>').addClass('body-part rightarm'));
}
function drawLeftLeg(){
  $('.legbox').prepend($('<div>').addClass('body-part leftleg'));
}
function drawRightLeg(){
  $('.legbox').prepend($('<div>').addClass('body-part rightleg'));
}
var drawSequence = [drawHead,drawTorso,drawLeftArm,drawRightArm,drawLeftLeg,drawRightLeg];



//

var wordlist = ['tree', 'mail', 'male', 'female'];

var guesses = [];
var targetWord = '';
var maxLives = 7;

function newWord() {
  targetWord = wordlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist.length)];
  return targetWord;
}
console.log('Your word is: ' + newWord());
//go through string of answer word and guesses
function obfuscateWord(){
  // temp variable
  var obWord = '';
  // loop through target word as an array and loop through with the guesses made
  for (var i=0; i<targetWord.length; i++) {
    //target letter word is not being guessed
    if (guesses.indexOf(targetWord[i].toLowerCase(), 0) == -1) {
      obWord += '_ ';
    } else {
      obWord += targetWord[i];
    }

  }
  return obWord;
}


//function to draw the spaces on the screen
function drawWord() {
  while (targetWord == '') {
    newWord();
  }
  //specify the div with targetWOrd ID
  $('#targetWord').html(obfuscateWord());
}

//for guessed Letters
function drawGuesses() {
  guesses.sort();
  $('#previousGuesses').html(guesses.join(', '));
  //console.log('this is guesses0: '+guesses)
}

//remove duplicates
function cleanGuess() {
  //temporary variable
  var uniqueGuesses = [];
  //for each guess perform function
  $.each(guesses, function(index, element) {
    //if guess is not in unique guesses push it, otherwise skip it
    //if element is not empty, test if it is in array
    if (element.length > 0 && $.inArray(element, uniqueGuesses) == -1) {
      uniqueGuesses.push(element);
      
    } else {
      alert('You already guessed this letter!');
    }
    
  });
  //override current guesses with uniqueGuesses
  guesses = uniqueGuesses;
}





//to populate the array with guesses, when a letter is input by user
function addGuess() {
  //filter out to only have a alphabet using a type test
  
  if(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test($('#guess').val()) && typeof $('#guess').val() !== "undefined") {
    //if passes test push into the array
    guesses.push($('#guess').val().toLowerCase());
  }
  //to 'empty' the user input
  $('#guess').val('');
}




// use for win or lose, isWinner true or false
function endGameDialog(isWinner) {
 if (isWinner) {
      //alert
      //set html of #endGame dialog b ox
      $('#endGameDialogTitle').html('You won');
      $('#endGameDialogContent').html('You guessed '+targetWord+' in '+guesses.length+' attempts!');
      
    } else {
   
      //alert
      //set html of #endGame dialog b ox
      $('#endGameDialogTitle').html('You Lost');
      $('#endGameDialogContent').html('The word was '+targetWord+'');
      
    }      
    
    //$('#endGameDialog'.modal('toggle'))
}

      
console.log('this is guesses: '+guesses)
function reviewLives() {
    var livesRemaining = maxLives,
        string = targetWord.toLowerCase();
console.log('this is string:' + string)
    for (var i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
        if (string.indexOf(guesses[i], 0) == -1) {
            livesRemaining--;
          //console.log(guesses[i])
        } 
    }
  
    if (livesRemaining === 6) {
      drawSequence[0]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===5) {
      drawSequence[1]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===4) {
      drawSequence[2]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===3) {
      drawSequence[3]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===2) {
      drawSequence[4]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===1) {
      drawSequence[5]();
      endGameDialog(false);
    }

  console.log('livesRemaining is: '+livesRemaining);

  
}

function checkIfWon() {
  if (obfuscateWord() == targetWord) {
    endGameDialog(true);
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  //setImage(0);
  targetWord = '';
  guesses = [];
  newWord();
  console.log(newWord())
}

//when key is pressed call the following functions
function update() {
  addGuess();
  cleanGuess();
  drawWord();
  drawGuesses();
  reviewLives();
  checkIfWon();
}
    
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  //loadWordlist();
  drawWord();
  drawGuesses();
  $('#guess').attr('onkeyup', 'update();');
});
```

```css
body { 
    font-family:sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-size:16pt;
}
/* Topmatter */
.topmatter {
    height:210px;    
}
.bottommatter{
    background:#f1f1f1;
    height:auto;
}
/* For the left 'Guess A Letter!' and 'Guessed Letter' boxes. */
.side-container {
    margin-top:45px;
    margin-left:130px;
    width:170px;
    text-align:center;
}
.container-title {
    color:#6f5a2d;
}
.input-area {
    width:75px;
    height:31px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:3pt;
    border: 1px #6f5a2d solid;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:#ebe2ce;
}
#letter-input {
    border:1px #6f5a2d solid;
    width:20pt;
    font-size:14pt;
    text-align:center;
}
.guessed-letter {
    color:#792c15;
}
/* Word Box */
.word-box {
    width:250px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:25px;
    text-align:center;
}
.word-display {
    background:#ebe2ce;
    border:1px #6f5a2d solid;
    height:31px;
    padding:3pt;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
.shown-letter {
    border-bottom: 3px #000 solid;
    padding: 0 2px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    color:#1c2025;
}
/* Hangman Area */
.hang-container {
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-right: 90px; 
    width:200px;
    height:205px;
    float:right;
}
.scaffolding-top {
    width:108px;
    height:5px;
    background:#332915;
}
.scaffolding-left {
    width:5px;
    height:200px;
    background:#332915;
    float:left;
}
.scaffolding-base {
    width:150px;
    height:5px;
    background:#332915;
}
.draw-area {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.rope {
    margin:auto;
    height:25px;
    width:5px;
    background:#a59885;
}
.head {
    margin:auto;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
.armbox {
    margin:auto;
    width:100px;
}
.leftarm {
    float:left;
    height:10px;
    width:45px;
    background:#000;
}
.rightarm {
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:45px;
    background:#000;
}
.torso {
    margin:auto;
    width:10px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
}
.legbox {
    margin:auto;
    height:60px;
    width:30px;
}
.leftleg {
    float:left;
    width:10px;
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
}
.rightleg {
    float:right;
    width:10px;
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
}
.pelvis {
    margin:auto;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:#000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hangman Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='topmatter'> 
      <div class='hang-container'>
        <div class='scaffolding-top'></div>
        <div class='scaffolding-left'></div>
    
        <div class='draw-area'>
          <div class='rope'></div>
        </div>
    
        <div class='scaffolding-base'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='side-container'>
        <div class='container-title'>Guess A Letter!</div>
        <div class='input-area'>
          <input id='guess' type='text' maxlength='1'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class='side-container'>
        <div class='container-title'>Guessed Letters</div>
        <div id="previousGuesses" class='input-area'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='bottommatter'>
        <div class='word-box'>
            <div class='word-display' id='targetWord'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id='endGameDialogTitle'>
    Win or Lose
  </div>
  
  
</body>
<script src='ui.js'></script>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

The problem starts when a wrong letter is entered **again**. While the first input of a wrong letter does draw part of the stickman, in the case when the user enters the **same** wrong letter **again**, an alert pops up to notify the key has been already pressed, and *it draws the same part of the stickman* (i.e. it will draw a second head). I know this is because of value livesRemaining is not being updated, which is causing it to draw the corresponding 'drawFoobar' once again. What kind of logic/statement can I use to prevent any additional draw attempts?

This is the specific function I am troubled with:`

```js
function reviewLives() {
    var livesRemaining = maxLives,
        string = targetWord.toLowerCase();
console.log('this is string:' + string)
    for (var i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
        if (string.indexOf(guesses[i], 0) == -1) {
            livesRemaining--;
          //console.log(guesses[i])
        } 
    }
  
    if (livesRemaining === 6) {
      drawSequence[0]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===5) {
      drawSequence[1]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===4) {
      drawSequence[2]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===3) {
      drawSequence[3]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===2) {
      drawSequence[4]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===1) {
      drawSequence[5]();
      endGameDialog(false);
    }

  console.log('livesRemaining is: '+livesRemaining);

  
}
```

`

Comment: I don't wanna give a full answer because it's a bit too much code to go through right now, but you might want to consider a different approach: instead of drawing only the next part every time a user guesses wrong, you should clear the entire view, and re-render the entire stickman based on how many lives you have left. To make this more optimized, you should build the stickman div structure as a a string, and then set that as the draw-area's innerHTML. This will prevent unnecessary DOM manipulations.

Comment: As an aside, it seems to me that `drawSequence[6-livesRemaining]()` could replace the existing if/else/else if structure and then you would just need a single if to test if the game is over.

Comment: @MatisLepik I see so render a new stickman with each input. What do you mean to build the stickman div structure as a string, do you mean something like pushing the drawfunctions into an array and then appending that array as the draw-area's innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable for example

```
var letterGuessed = false;
```

and in the cleanGuess function when you alert the the text 'You already guessed this letter!' set the variable letterGuessed to true

```
alert('You already guessed this letter!');
letterGuessed = true;//add
```

and then in the reviewLives function check if the variable letterGuessed equals to false first and after getting out of the for loop set the variable letterGuessed back to false
like this

```
function reviewLives() {
    var livesRemaining = maxLives,
        string = targetWord.toLowerCase();
console.log('this is string:' + string)
    for (var i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
        if (!letterGuessed && string.indexOf(guesses[i], 0) == -1) {//==========add !letterGuessed && 
            livesRemaining--;
          //console.log(guesses[i])
        } 
    }
    letterGuessed = false;//==========add

    if (livesRemaining === 6) {
      drawSequence[0]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===5) {
      drawSequence[1]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===4) {
      drawSequence[2]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===3) {
      drawSequence[3]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===2) {
      drawSequence[4]();
    } else if (livesRemaining===1) {
      drawSequence[5]();
      endGameDialog(false);
    }

  console.log('livesRemaining is: '+livesRemaining);

}
```